# I want to create serial numbers in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, database-sequence

I want to create a serial number in Oracle.
I have tried this query

```
alter table tablename add(ID NUMBER);

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_ID START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MAXVALUE 31611805 MINVALUE 1 NOCYCLE;

UPDATE tablename SET ID= SEQ_ID.NEXTVAL
```

I have,

```
NID
----- 
ABD90
BGJ89
HSA76
```

and I want:

```
ID NID
---------
1  ABD90 
2  BGJ89
3  HSA76
```

Above code is not working. I am new to oracle.Please help in generating above result.

Comment: what's not working , what's the error

Comment: It is not showing any error but it is not giving any result as well.

Comment: An `update` does not return any results

Comment: I mean to say the result was not updated in respective column.

Comment: Is this an exact duplicate? It looks to me more like the other question is him trying to use a front end to do it, and having not had success this q is him trying to do it directly in the database

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add unique ID for each NID then, you can do it this way-

```
  UPDATE tablename t
       SET t.ID =
              (SELECT SEQ_ID.NEXTVAL
                 FROM tablename sub_t
                WHERE t.NID = sub_t.NID);
```